# How to Filter Paid or Not Paid Student In laravel

Tags: laravel, where-clause, where-in

I have just created some payment system for a school and I need to filter my data to `Paid` or `Not Paid` category.

```php
$queryBuilder = Student::query()
    ->leftJoin('fee_scheem_maps', 'students.students_id', '=', 'fee_scheem_maps.sfc_student_id')
    ->leftJoin('fee_scheems', 'fee_scheem_maps.sfc_feescheem_id', '=', 'fee_scheems.fee_scheems_id')
    ->leftJoin('individual_fee_scheems', 'fee_scheem_maps.sifc_feescheem_id', '=', 'individual_fee_scheems.ifs_id')
    ->leftJoin('fee_groups', 'fee_scheems.fee_scheems_id', '=', 'fee_groups.fg_fee_scheem_id')
    ->leftJoin('school_fee_collectors', 'students.students_id', '=', 'school_fee_collectors.fc_student_id')
    // ->Where('school_fee_collectors.fc_fee_group_id', $fromDate)
    // ->orWhereNull('school_fee_collectors.fc_fee_group_id', $pstatus)
    // ->orWhereNull('school_fee_collectors.fc_fee_group_id', $fromDate)
    ->when($fromDate, function ($query) use ($fromDate) {
        return $query->where('school_fee_collectors.fc_fee_group_id', $fromDate);
    })
    ->select('*', DB::raw('count(students_id) as total'));
```

It is working fine with one clause: I need to randomly choose `where` or `notWhere` in my case...

Comment: What is your problem ? I did not understand.

Comment: Ok I need Filter My Student Payment Data check with Fee Collector table . So I need to Choose In my front end to select Paid or Not Paid Status. I now i created Its only i can filter One condition only .. When I use Where Clause its show Paid Student only and When i Use Where Null its Showing Unpaid Student Only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryBuilder = Student::query()
    ->leftJoin('fee_scheem_maps', 'students.students_id', '=', 'fee_scheem_maps.sfc_student_id')
    ->leftJoin('fee_scheems', 'fee_scheem_maps.sfc_feescheem_id', '=', 'fee_scheems.fee_scheems_id')
    ->leftJoin('individual_fee_scheems', 'fee_scheem_maps.sifc_feescheem_id', '=', 'individual_fee_scheems.ifs_id')
    ->leftJoin('fee_groups', 'fee_scheems.fee_scheems_id', '=', 'fee_groups.fg_fee_scheem_id')
    ->leftJoin('school_fee_collectors', 'students.students_id', '=', 'school_fee_collectors.fc_student_id')
    ->when($fromDate, function ($query) use ($fromDate) {
        return $query->where('school_fee_collectors.fc_fee_group_id', $fromDate);
    })

->where(function($query) use ($request){
    if($request->paid_status){
       $query->where('table_name.columName',$request->paid_status)
    }
})->select('*', DB::raw('count(students_id) as total'));
```

you can use where like this ,  when your $request->paid_status is null means have no filter about paid not paid thats time query is return everything but when is have filter thats time only this where is working

```
->where(function($query) use ($request){
    if($request->paid_status){
       $query->where('table_name.columName',$request->paid_status)
    }
})
```